# Override class member variable

Tags: c++, oop

I'm running into an inheritance problem and I don't know if my solution is elegant. I have classes like this

```
class Var
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething();
}
class DerivedVar : public Var
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething();
    void doSomethingElse();
}
```

I also have MyDerived that inherits from MyBase. MyBase has a member of type Var while MyDerived needs to have a member of DerivedVar so it can call doSomething(). Currently, I'm using template to solve this problem

```
template<typename VarType>
class MyBase
{
protected:
    VarType var;
public:
    MyBase() { var.doSomething(); }
}

class MyDerived : public MyBase<DerivedVar>
{
public:
    MyDerived() : MyBase() { var.doSomethingElse(); }

}
```

I want to know if there's a better way to do this (eg. without the need of using template)

Comment: You might find reading about CRTP interesting if you don't know it.

Comment: Well... if it's no bother for you to add a level of indirection and allocation on the heap, you can always store a pointer...

Answer (score 1):

If you want or need to avoid the templating then you need to allocate the covariant type data member dynamically.

A good approach is then to pass a factory up the constructor chain (it can be a defaulted constructor argument), and invoke it in the base class.

An ungood approach, but very popular in the early 1990s, is to use two-phase initialization.

OK, I anticipated issue that you have not yet run into.

But you will. ;-)

That said, if you can make the template approach work that's probably best.

Most direct solution, least amount of workarounds and code and design adaptions.